# Add event to fullCalendar integrated with spring MVC by ajax request

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, fullcalendar

I want to add new event to fullCalendar and send this event as a json object to the server side which is springMVC by ajax request and every time the request is send ,the response is "400 bad request"

the ajax request

`$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insertSession",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: dataObject,
      success: function (result) {
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
      },
      error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert(" Can't Save your Event: " + error);
      }});`

the dataObject = `{ id: null, start: "05/29/2017 12:00:00 am", durationInMinutes: "159", room: "1", sessionType: "2", course: "2", event: null }`

the business logic

`@RequestMapping(value = "/insertSession", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSession(@RequestBody SessionDTO session, BindingResult result) {
// do some code
}`

SessionDTO

```
`class SessionDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String start;
   private int durationInMinutes;
private int course;
private int room;
private int event;
private int sessionType;
// setter and getter method}`
```

Comment: Can you replace `data: dataObject` with `data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)` and try?

Comment: Also, if you could paste `SessionDTO` pojo class, it would be of great help

Comment: @harshavmb i added `SessionDTO` to the post

Comment: Did you change `data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)` before passing your jsondata to controller?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @harshavmb

Comment: Has `JSON.stringify(dataObject)` worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it has worked fine :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you! Feel free to tick my answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP 400 bad request` is usually seen when browser/clients sent some data to server and servers couldn't understand it. Clients shouldn't repeat the request without modifications.

In your case,

> dataObject = { id: null, start: "05/29/2017 12:00:00 am",
>   durationInMinutes: "159", room: "1", sessionType: "2", course: "2",
>   event: null }

is being sent to server and it had problems understanding the data.

Javascript has a utility function to exchange data to/from the server. 
`JSON.stringify(dataObject)` will convert the javascript object to a string in JSON notion.

Hope this helps..!!!

Comment: Thanks , this helps me more